# Java path confusion- and I possibly made it worse

Tags: java, terminal, path, directory, javac

So I installed JDK on windows 10, and followed a tutorial to make sure I did everything correctly (because I am a beginner). However, when I tried running a program to test it (HelloWorld), after compiling, I got this message:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe.
```

So, after some googling, I came upon the solution that I needed to remove that directory from my Path, on Environment Variables.
This did not solve anything, the message still showed up, and now:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Only after did I realise I can't undo that path change, and am now at a complete loss.
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Windows fundamental: You need to add the full path to the Java \bin directory to your PATH, but it's only a convenience.  If you type the full path you can always execute any .exe, including javac and java.

Comment: How did you add the path to your environment variable in there first place? Looked like you might have typed in a placeholder instead of changing it to something real.

Comment: @duffymo path _has_ been added, at least, it seemed so last time I checked, but just to be sure, how should I type the full path?

Comment: @Dave I went to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings (opened System Properties) > Environment Variables (opened new window with same name) - then set JAVA_HOME as new user variable, and added %JAVA_HOME%bin to Path in System variables. I'm unsure as to where I made a mistake?

Comment: Make sure it's %JAVA_HOME%\bin.  Check it by typing "java -version" in a command shell.  If you don't get the right answer back, then the PATH is still wrong.

Comment: well, still wrong answer, so must mean path is wrong, but I don't know how? I even followed the step-by-step instructions given in one of the answers, is there anywhere else I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To place the environment variable for Java JDK within the Windows 10 System Environment follow these steps:

**1)** Locate your JAVA home folder (directory). By Default I believe this is placed in the "C:\Program Files\Java" but this can be changed during installation so you will need to remember where it was installed if you've decided to stray from default. I believe the installer for the JDK should have also set an environment variable for you;

**2)** Open the Windows **File Explorer** application (not Internet Explorer);

**3)** In the far left pane of File Explorer locate and right-click your mouse pointer on **This PC** then select **Properties** from the displayed popup menu. A **System** window is opened and displayed;

**4)** From the **System** window select (left-click) the link item titled: **Advanced system settings** located on the left side of the window. A **System Properties** dialog window is opened and displayed;

**5)** Select the **Environment Variables...** button located on the bottom right corner of the **System Properties** dialog window. The **Environment Variables** dialog window is opened and displayed. There are two list sections in this dialog with the top section titled **User variables for *YourLoginName*** and the bottom section titled **System variables**.

**6)** Within the top section (*User variables for YourLoginName*) of the *Environment variables* dialog window you should see a variable titled **JAVA_HOME**.

If you do then select it, then select the related **Edit** button, a Input Box is opened and you should see the path to your particular JDK located within the **Variable Value** field (perhaps: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60**). If this field is blank then enter or paste the path to your particular JDK into the field and select the **OK** button.

If you ***do not*** see the **JAVA_HOME** variable within the top section (User variables for *YourLoginName*) of the *Environment variables* dialog window then select the **New** button related to the **User variables for *YourLoginName*** section and within the displayed Input Box enter **JAVA_HOME** into the **Variable Name** field and then enter or paste the path to your particular JDK within the **Variable Value** field (you can also browse to you JDK folder). Select the **OK** button within the Input Box when your entries are done.

**7)** Now look in the bottom section of the **Environment Variables** dialog window (**System variables**). You should see a variable named **Path** or **PATH** within the list (scroll down if you have to).

If you see the variable named **PATH** then select it then select the **Edit** button related to the **System variables** section, a **Edit environment variable** dialog window is opened and displayed. You should be able to see the path: **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath** located within the list (scroll if need to). If you don't then select the **New** button and enter: **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath** then hit your keyboard **ENTER** Key. Now, with your newly entered path highlighted, select the **Move Up** button until your path is located at the top of the list. Select the **OK** button when done.

If you **DO NOT** see the variable named **PATH** (and to be honest...*YOU SHOULD*) then select it then select the **New** button related to the **System variables** section, a **New System Variable** Input Box is opened and displayed. In the **Variable name** field enter: **PATH**  and in the **Variable value** field enter: **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath**. Select the **OK** button when done.

**8)** Select the **OK** Button located at the bottom of the **Environment Variables** dialog window.

**9)** Select the **OK** button located at the bottom of the **System Properties** dialog window.

**10)** Close the **System** window.

**11)** **Restart your computer**.

If all worked well you should be good to go.

Comment: Followed all the steps, everything is as it should be (at least, what is mentioned here), restarted the computer, and still

Comment: C:\>java
   The system cannot find the fileC:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe.

C:\>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: (Okay, that does not look pretty, but basically, no change)

Answer (score 0):

I have had installed Oracle and I was not aware that there was a JRE module inside. And besides, it had already automatically added a path for java here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Additionally, I've had JDK 13.0.2

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin
```

in here. [it was like this before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGB2k.png)
and when I tried to compare java -version and javac -version, the respective results were this:

```
java -version  >> 13.0.2
javac -version   >> 1.08.282
```

Then reading this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077770/14548725
I went to the path via directories (in windows 10 search bar write environments, click and open it. Goto system variables>Path> you will see the list of apps.)
I realized that the apps have a hierarchy and "java" command tool selects the first one it sees from the list.
So that I changed the order and did it like this:
[current app order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG2ii.png)
Then I restarted windows powershell. and

```
java -version  >> 13.0.2
javac -version   >> 13.0.2
```

results has become same and consistent, luckyly.
and I examined my java file on desktop. And done!

Answer (score -1):

you should set up the java environment correctly.
First add JAVA_HOME  the base path of your jdk to your system.
then add %JAVA_HOME%\bin
I hope this gona be helpful for you.

Comment: do you mean set JAVA_HOME as user variable, and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to Path? if so, already done. Haven't added %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin though, so will do that now. If this is not what you meant, can you please clarify? thank you

Comment: oh okay, will not do that part then

Comment: I sorry to let the wrong answer confusing you. And I particularly compared the jdk/bin with jre/bin, then I found that the jre/bin is a subset of jdk/bin.